# Helping on how to solve ambiguous grammar

Tags: ambiguous-grammar

Show that the following grammar is ambiguous. (To show that a grammar is ambiguous, you must demonstrate that it can generate two parse trees for the same string.)    `

```
`person::= woman|man
    woman::= willma|betty|empty
    man::=fred|barney|empty

below is what I did.
person
  |
woman
  |
willma
  |
woman
  |
betty
  |
woman
  |
empty
----------
person
  |
 man
  |
fred
  |
 man
  |
barney
  |
 man
  |
empty
```

Comment: No, sorry, it's wrong.  You cannot derive <woman> from <wilma>, according to your grammar, or <man> from <fred>.  However, you are right in that the grammar is ambiguous for <empty>, and one derivation is via <woman> the other is via <man>.  I'm assuming you want to try to work the solution out for yourself, if you can.

Comment: @JeffreyKegler     here the change, New Post:_italic_ **bold** `code`
     **  person
        /           \
     woman   man
       |              |
     willma    fred
       |              |
      betty    barney
       |              |
      empty    empty**

Comment: @Sammy_Smith -- Sorry, I could not follow the format in your new attempt.  IIRC, Stackoverflow does not allow the same formatting in comments as in questions.  You might try editing your original, adding a note that it is edited.

Answer (score 0):

empty could be a leaf under both man and woman and is thus ambiguous. It should be a direct child of person.

```
person::= woman|man|empty
woman::= willma|betty
man::=fred|barney
```

Comment: the problem I gave you above is from my book. I was asking did I solve the problem correctly. thank you